# How to get CKEditor form textfield value

Tags: ckeditor

In `CKEditor`, I have a `textfield` (given by the Forms plugin).

How can I get its value? Also, how can I enumerate all the textfields?

Answer (score 0):

If you using jquery:

```
$('textarea.CKEditorClass').each(function() {
   //enumerate
});
```

- CKEditorClass is class of element textfields

or just get quantity

```
$('textarea.CKEditorClass').length
```

For get content

```
CKEDITOR.instances[id].getData();
```

- `id` is `id` of element textfield

Comment: How does this help? I'm talking about getting the textfields added by this plugin  http://ckeditor.com/addon/forms

Comment: Oh sorry, you can add common specific class on each textfield and then you can easy accessible to each of them, please check before that they haven't common class for CKEditor already. I hope that it's help you, otherwise do you have maybe demo this editor with forms plugin ? (then I'll be able to analize html source)